# How reliable a method is this to detect zoom % on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, zooming

```
    // Init
    var initialWidth = window.innerWidth;

    // Called when zoomed in
    function handleResize(){

        // Viewport dimension, this is affected by zoom
        var viewportwidth = window.innerWidth;         
        var zoomAmount = initialWidth/viewportwidth;   

        $('#lol').html('<p>Your viewport width is '+viewportwidth+'<br />Your native width is ' + initialWidth + '<br />Total zoom is ' + zoomAmount + '</p>');
    }
```

Then in the body:

```
<body onresize="handleResize()">
<div id="lol" style="font-size:30px;"></div>
```

It seems to be accurate within +-7% on my MobiOne iPhone simulator, but I don't have a real iPhone to test this on.  Is this a good solution, or am I going to run into problems later?

The main issue is if the page loads pre-zoomed in then the %'s get messed up, is it ever possible to open a web page on an iPhone zoomed in or will it always default to 100%?

Comment: As far as the load size of the page on the iPhone, look for more information about the "viewport meta tag" to see what sort of syntax is appropriate for what initial size you'd prefer. [This page](http://chriscoyier.net/2009/01/25/iphone-meta-tag-for-viewport-maintaining-scale-on-orientation-change/) shows one usage that disables user ability to zoom altogether, which is probably not what you want, but you can use the width attribute to force a particular initial size.

Comment: @Ithi thanks, but people are misunderstanding my question, I don't want to FORCE a zoom, I want to know what the current zoom is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really comment on how effective this technique will be, however, I would suggest that you probably shouldn't even try.  Generally speaking trying to force or adapt to zoom levels isn't a great idea - there are a great variety of smart-phone devices, and it is very unlikely that you will be able to reliably detect / adjust the zoom levels on all of them.  Instead I would argue that your time would be better spent trying to make your site look good at any zoom level.

Comment: My site shows a magazine.  When you are zoomed out, it loads the low res version, when you zoom in, it loads the hi res version.  No way about this really.

Comment: So, let me get this straight, you are going to load the page, detect the devices zoom level, and then make an AJAX request for the appropriate version?  I can see why you might want to do this to save some bandwidth.